# How to use two different comment apps?

Tags: django, django-comments

For example I want to use my custom comment app (with ranking features, threading, etc) in some pages and in other pages I want to use standard django comment app.
How can i do this?

thanks

Comment: do you know the concepts of when to use one and when to use another? those concepts are related with your models, sites framework, etc?

Comment: i want to use one on pages where users can write reviews (my custom comments) and  another on pages where users can comment images/videos. My problem is how to defined more then one comment app and use at the same time